# How does a DOCKER communicate with a Windows client

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

I understand that Docker runs on Linux kernel

Lets say, I deploy an application (SORRY!! I can't disclose the application due to confidentiality reasons) on a CentOS Docker image. The application is known to be compatible with both Windows and Linux.

So now, if I want to run some some program/script on that deployed image but the client that I am using is Windows. Here are two questions that I have,

1. Is it even possible to use Windows machine to execute the programs/scripts in the remote Docker image?
2. If answer to question 1 is yes, then how are the system calls in Windows mapped to the equivalent system calls in the Linux environment of Docker.

Comment: Application deployment is on-topic over at ServerFault. But I wonder if this is too trivial for them. Network communications is TCP/IP nowadays, and Windows system calls are **not** mapped to Linuix environemnts. (Why would they?)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to use Windows machine to execute the programs/scripts in the remote Docker image?

No: you would need to run the docker image in a Linux VM running on your Windows.
The system calls would be to the VM Linux kernel.

A [docker image for Windows (server 2016)](https://blog.docker.com/2015/08/tp-docker-engine-windows-server-2016/) would be built specifically for Windows.